# avr_g++ compiler error: expected primary-expression before '.' token (C code in .ino)

Tags: avrdude, compilation-errors, build, avr-toolchain

The compiler is complaining about a macro defined in mjson.h

```
Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:135:28: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

#define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f) .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)

                           ^
```

The code compiles and links ok on Windows 7 platform running Visual Studio and Ubuntu running gcc.

The full build errors are:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10805 -build-path AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446 -warnings=all -build-cache AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_49629 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10805 -build-path AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446 -warnings=all -build-cache AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_49629 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446\sketch\test_microjson.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IDocuments\Arduino\libraries\microjson" "AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446\sketch\test_microjson.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IDocuments\Arduino\libraries\microjson" "Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson\mjson.c" -o "nul"
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IDocuments\Arduino\libraries\microjson" "AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446\sketch\test_microjson.ino.cpp" -o "AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IDocuments\Arduino\libraries\microjson" "AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446\sketch\test_microjson.ino.cpp" -o "AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_106446\sketch\test_microjson.ino.cpp.o"
In file included from Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:7:0:

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:135:28: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

 #define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f) .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)

                            ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:31:29: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTOBJECT'

   { "start_pin", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, start_pin) },

                             ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:135:28: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

 #define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f) .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)

                            ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:32:27: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTOBJECT'

   { "end_pin", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, end_pin) },

                           ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:135:28: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

 #define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f) .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)

                            ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:33:30: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTOBJECT'

   { "colour_red", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, colour_red) },

                              ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:135:28: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

 #define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f) .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)

                            ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:34:32: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTOBJECT'

   { "colour_green", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, colour_green) },

                                ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:135:28: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

 #define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f) .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)

                            ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:35:31: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTOBJECT'

   { "colour_blue", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, colour_blue) },

                               ^

test_microjson:40: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

   { "type", t_string, .addr.string = thenode.type, .len = sizeof(thenode.type) },

                       ^

In file included from Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:7:0:

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:137:2: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

  .addr.array.element_type = t_structobject, \

  ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:41:26: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTARRAY'

   { "sections", t_array, STRUCTARRAY(thenode.thelight, section_attrs, &num_sections) },

                          ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:138:2: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

  .addr.array.arr.objects.subtype = e, \

  ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:41:26: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTARRAY'

   { "sections", t_array, STRUCTARRAY(thenode.thelight, section_attrs, &num_sections) },

                          ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:139:2: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

  .addr.array.arr.objects.base = (char*)a, \

  ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:41:26: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTARRAY'

   { "sections", t_array, STRUCTARRAY(thenode.thelight, section_attrs, &num_sections) },

                          ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:140:2: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

  .addr.array.arr.objects.stride = sizeof(a[0]), \

  ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:41:26: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTARRAY'

   { "sections", t_array, STRUCTARRAY(thenode.thelight, section_attrs, &num_sections) },

                          ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:141:2: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

  .addr.array.count = n, \

  ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:41:26: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTARRAY'

   { "sections", t_array, STRUCTARRAY(thenode.thelight, section_attrs, &num_sections) },

                          ^

Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson/mjson.h:142:2: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

  .addr.array.maxlen = (int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

  ^

Documents\Arduino\test_microjson\test_microjson.ino:41:26: note: in expansion of macro 'STRUCTARRAY'

   { "sections", t_array, STRUCTARRAY(thenode.thelight, section_attrs, &num_sections) },

                          ^

Using library microjson in folder: Documents\Arduino\libraries\microjson (legacy)
exit status 1
expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

test_microjson.ino:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <stddef.h>  // offsetof - used in STRUCTOBJECT macro

#include <mjson.h>

#define MAX_SECTIONS 6  // we support up to six different sections on strip

// in json sections is an array of these light options
typedef struct light_section {
  int start_pin;
  int end_pin;
  int colour_red;
  int colour_green;
  int colour_blue;
}lights_t;


typedef struct node {
  char type[20];
  lights_t thelight[MAX_SECTIONS];
} node_t;

node_t thenode;

static int num_sections;

const struct json_attr_t section_attrs[] = {
  { "start_pin", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, start_pin) },
  { "end_pin", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, end_pin) },
  { "colour_red", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, colour_red) },
  { "colour_green", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, colour_green) },
  { "colour_blue", t_integer, STRUCTOBJECT(lights_t, colour_blue) },
  { NULL },
};

static const struct json_attr_t json_attrs[] = {
  { "type", t_string, .addr.string = thenode.type, .len = sizeof(thenode.type) },
  { "sections", t_array, STRUCTARRAY(thenode.thelight, section_attrs, &num_sections) },
  { NULL },
};


void setup() {

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // this check is only needed on the Leonardo:
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  // start the Ethernet connection:
  Serial.println("microjson test");

  static const char *s =
    "{ \"type\": \"section\", \"sections\": [{ \"start_pin\": 0, \"end_pin\": 71, \"colour_red\": 0, \"colour_green\": 255, \"colour_blue\": 0 }, { \"start_pin\": 216, \"end_pin\": 287, \"colour_red\": 255, \"colour_green\": 0, \"colour_blue\": 0 }] }";

  int status = json_read_object(s, json_attrs, NULL);

  if (status != 0)
    Serial.println(json_error_string(status));

  Serial.print("found ");
  Serial.print(num_sections);
  Serial.print(" sections");

  Serial.print("type=");
  Serial.println(thenode.type);

  //printf("type=%s\n", thenode.type);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_sections; ++i) {
    Serial.print("section [");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("]: start_pin=");
    Serial.print(thenode.thelight[i].start_pin);
    Serial.print(", end_pin=");
    Serial.print(thenode.thelight[i].end_pin);
    Serial.print(", red=");
    Serial.print(thenode.thelight[i].colour_red);
    Serial.print(", green=");
    Serial.print(thenode.thelight[i].colour_green);
    Serial.print(", blue=");
    Serial.println(thenode.thelight[i].colour_blue);    
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

And the offending macro in mjson.h STRUCTOBJECT.  And also STRUCTARRAY.  Here they are:

```
 * Use the following macros to declare template initializers for structobject
 * arrays.  Writing the equivalents out by hand is error-prone.
 *
 * STRUCTOBJECT takes a structure name s, and a fieldname f in s.
 *
 * STRUCTARRAY takes the name of a structure array, a pointer to a an
 * initializer defining the subobject type, and the address of an integer to
 * store the length in.
 */
#define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f)  .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)
#define STRUCTARRAY(a, e, n) \
    .addr.array.element_type = t_structobject, \
    .addr.array.arr.objects.subtype = e, \
    .addr.array.arr.objects.base = (char*)a, \
    .addr.array.arr.objects.stride = sizeof(a[0]), \
    .addr.array.count = n, \
    .addr.array.maxlen = (int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))
```

How can I fix this to get it to compile using Arduino avr-g++ ?

mjson.h is from microjson library.  I can provide more details of that if required.

mjson.h header:

```
/* Structures for JSON parsing using only fixed-extent memory
 *
 * This file is Copyright (c) 2014 by Eric S. Raymond.
 * BSD terms apply: see the file COPYING in the distribution root for details.
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define NITEMS(x) (int)(sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

typedef enum {t_integer, t_uinteger, t_real,
          t_string, t_boolean, t_character,
          t_time,
          t_object, t_structobject, t_array,
          t_check, t_ignore} 
    json_type;

struct json_enum_t {
    char    *name;
    int     value;
};

struct json_array_t {
    json_type element_type;
    union {
      struct {
        const struct json_attr_t *subtype;
        char *base;
        size_t stride;
      } objects;
      struct {
        char **ptrs;
        char *store;
        int storelen;
      } strings;
      struct {
        int *store;
      } integers;
      struct {
        unsigned int *store;
      } uintegers;
      struct {
        double *store;
      } reals;
      struct {
        bool *store;
      } booleans;
    } arr;
    int *count, maxlen;
};

struct json_attr_t {
    char *attribute;
    json_type type;

    union {
      int *integer;
      unsigned int *uinteger;
      double *real;
      char *string;
      bool *boolean;
      char *character;
      struct json_array_t array;
      size_t offset;
    } addr;

    union {
      int integer;
      unsigned int uinteger;
      double real;
      bool boolean;
      char character;
      char *check;
    } dflt;

    size_t len;
    const struct json_enum_t *map;
    bool nodefault;
};

#define JSON_ATTR_MAX   31  /* max chars in JSON attribute name */
#define JSON_VAL_MAX    512 /* max chars in JSON value part */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int json_read_object(const char *, const struct json_attr_t *,
             /*@null@*/const char **);
int json_read_array(const char *, const struct json_array_t *,
            /*@null@*/const char **);
const /*@observer@*/char *json_error_string(int);

void json_enable_debug(int, FILE *);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#define JSON_ERR_OBSTART    1   /* non-WS when expecting object start */
#define JSON_ERR_ATTRSTART  2   /* non-WS when expecting attrib start */
#define JSON_ERR_BADATTR    3   /* unknown attribute name */
#define JSON_ERR_ATTRLEN    4   /* attribute name too long */
#define JSON_ERR_NOARRAY    5   /* saw [ when not expecting array */
#define JSON_ERR_NOBRAK     6   /* array element specified, but no [ */
#define JSON_ERR_STRLONG    7   /* string value too long */
#define JSON_ERR_TOKLONG    8   /* token value too long */
#define JSON_ERR_BADTRAIL   9   /* garbage while expecting comma or } or ] */
#define JSON_ERR_ARRAYSTART 10  /* didn't find expected array start */
#define JSON_ERR_OBJARR     11  /* error while parsing object array */
#define JSON_ERR_SUBTOOLONG 12  /* too many array elements */
#define JSON_ERR_BADSUBTRAIL    13  /* garbage while expecting array comma */
#define JSON_ERR_SUBTYPE    14  /* unsupported array element type */
#define JSON_ERR_BADSTRING  15  /* error while string parsing */
#define JSON_ERR_CHECKFAIL  16  /* check attribute not matched */
#define JSON_ERR_NOPARSTR   17  /* can't support strings in parallel arrays */
#define JSON_ERR_BADENUM    18  /* invalid enumerated value */
#define JSON_ERR_QNONSTRING 19  /* saw quoted value when expecting nonstring */
#define JSON_ERR_NONQSTRING 19  /* didn't see quoted value when expecting string */
#define JSON_ERR_MISC       20  /* other data conversion error */
#define JSON_ERR_BADNUM     21  /* error while parsing a numerical argument */
#define JSON_ERR_NULLPTR    22  /* unexpected null value or attribute pointer */

/*
 * Use the following macros to declare template initializers for structobject
 * arrays.  Writing the equivalents out by hand is error-prone.
 *
 * STRUCTOBJECT takes a structure name s, and a fieldname f in s.
 *
 * STRUCTARRAY takes the name of a structure array, a pointer to a an
 * initializer defining the subobject type, and the address of an integer to
 * store the length in.
 */
#define STRUCTOBJECT(s, f)  .addr.offset = offsetof(s, f)
#define STRUCTARRAY(a, e, n) \
    .addr.array.element_type = t_structobject, \
    .addr.array.arr.objects.subtype = e, \
    .addr.array.arr.objects.base = (char*)a, \
    .addr.array.arr.objects.stride = sizeof(a[0]), \
    .addr.array.count = n, \
    .addr.array.maxlen = (int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

/* json.h ends here */
```

Comment: why do you want to use this library with Arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ino is compiled as C++. your test is C code. put the C code in a .c file and the declaration in .h file and include the .h in .ino

I created a test.c, copied the content of your main.c into it and renamed the main function to test().

Then I created a test.h with

```
#ifndef test_h
#define test_h

extern "C" void test(char * buff);

#endif
```

and in ino setup() I call `test();`

it compiles. It runs. Output:

```
2 sections
type=section
section [0]: start_pin=  0, end_pin= 71, red=  0, green=255, blue=  0
section [1]: start_pin=216, end_pin=287, red=255, green= 53, blue=  0
```

in ino

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  char buff[700];
  test(buff);
  Serial.print(buff);
}
```

in .c

```
void test(char* buff) {

  static const char *s =
      "{ \"type\": \"section\", \"sections\": [{ \"start_pin\": 0, \"end_pin\": 71, \"colour_red\": 0, \"colour_green\": 255, \"colour_blue\": 0 }, { \"start_pin\": 216, \"end_pin\": 287, \"colour_red\": 255, \"colour_green\": 0, \"colour_blue\": 0 }] }";

  int status = json_read_object(s, json_attrs, NULL);

  if (status != 0) {
    sprintf(buff, json_error_string(status));
    return;
  }

  int pos = sprintf(buff, "%d sections\n", num_sections);

  pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "type=%s\n", thenode.type);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_sections; ++i) {
    pos +=
        sprintf(buff + pos,
            "section [%d]: start_pin=%3d, end_pin=%3d, red=%3d, green=%3d, blue=%3d\n",
            i, thenode.thelight[i].start_pin, thenode.thelight[i].end_pin,
            thenode.thelight[i].colour_red, thenode.thelight[i].colour_green,
            thenode.thelight[i].colour_blue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I uploaded wrong exercising code.  Changed now to code I used in ino file

Comment: Do I put the test.h and test.c in the same folder as the test_microjson.ino or would I put in same folder as /Android/libraries/microjson ?

Comment: to project folder. to .ino.

Comment: Better but getting multiple definition of `test' at link stage now. Actually changed to testmj and now just getting error multiple definition of section_attrs

Comment: add guard #ifdef to mjson.h and test.h. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: yes already added guard - but still get this error. I put mjson.c & h and testmj.c & h in libraries/microjson folder.